# How to inspect empty rows in uploaded csv

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

Here i have a csv file which have contains numerous contacts rows, and these rows ae saved to my database table. Now i just want to inspect empty rows from uploaded csv by customer.

**Here is an example csv with some empty rows**

[image]

In this above csv, have 3rd and 6th rows are empty. so want to inspect these empty row number and discard csv with error.

**Here is my csv code**

```
$filename = $_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"];
            if ($_FILES["csv_file"]["size"] > 0) {
                $file       = fopen($filename, "r");
                $importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",");
                $counter    = 1;
                while (!feof($file)) {
                    if ($counter > 1) {
                        $alldata[] = fgetcsv($file);
                    }
                    $counter++;
                }
                fclose($file);
                $csvfieldcounter = 1;
                foreach ($alldata as $importdata) {
                    $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
                    $userId   = $userdata['id'];
                    $status   = 'Y';
                    if ($importdata[4] == 'Disable' || $importdata[4] == 'disable')
                        $status = 'N';
                    else if ($importdata[4] == 'Enable' || $importdata[4] == 'enable')
                        $status = 'Y';
                    $data = array(
                        'customer_name' => $importdata[0],
                        'customer_email' => $importdata[1],
                        'customer_mobile' => $importdata[2],
                        'birth_date' => $importdata[3],
                        'status' => $status,
                        'user_id' => $userId,
                        'cat_type' => $file_cat
                    );
                    if ($importdata[2]) {
                        $run = $this->db->insert('customer', $data);
                        $csvfieldcounter++;
                        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
                    }
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('csv_imported','Your CSV have been successfully imported.');
                redirect('/customer', $csvfieldcounter);
            }
```

I just want a little help for get that. your kind efforts would be appreciated  Thanks :)

Comment: is it safe to say when the first column is empty don't check the rest? unset will remove an entry from the array or continue will skip the logic for that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use below mentioned library. This will help you address above issue also it will decrease lines of code in your controller.

https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

This will help you.

If you worried about how to use than check below mentioned code.

```
$this->load->library('Parsecsv');
$csv = new Parsecsv($file);
$users = $csv->data;
$noOfUsers = count($users);
foreach($users as $user):
   if(!empty($user)):

      // Write your code

   endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me about the name of that liabrary?

Comment: `Parsecsv` is the name of library and you can find it here -- https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Comment: Thanks @Shyaam, but their is an issue..!

Comment: Yes, You can share your error, I will help you to implement this in CI

Comment: can you crate a chat, then i'll describe you my issue more briefly. Thanks